# Changing backColor of button when pressed Enter in keyboard

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, backcolor

```
 Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            Button1.BackColor = Color.Aqua
        End If
    End Sub
```

I want to change the BackColor of the button if enter key is pressed but it does nothing when I pressed the enter key. Form KeyPreview is set to true.If Enter key is replaced by another key the code is executed

Comment: Firstly, why tag this question VBA? Please read the description of a tag before adding it to your question.

Comment: As for the question, have you checked whether that code is even being executed? You should have done that before posting here and included that information in your question. Code can't do something if it's not executed. If you haven't set the `KeyPreview` property to `True` on the form then it won't raise keyboard events when a child control has focus.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the code is executing when enter key is replaced by another keys .The KeyPreview property is set to True

Comment: I just tested and the form raises the `KeyDown` event if a `TextBox` or `ListBox` has focus but not for a `Button`. It presumably has to do with the `Enter` having special meaning for the `Button`, i.e. causing a click. Are you seeing the same behaviour? If that's the issue then you may have to handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event for the `Button` separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override [ProcessCmdKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey?view=net-5.0) like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        If keyData = Keys.Enter Then
            Button1.BackColor = Color.Aqua
        End If
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function

End Class
```